# Is this a good practice object for diplaying messages?

Tags: javascript

It works, I've tested it.  What I want to know is - is this good practice.  Obviously I could have just used an associative array and called it.  But I wanted to encapuslate it into an object with state.

```
var View_message = function(div)
{    this.messages = 
    {
        empty: 'Please complete all fields',
        empty_bm: 'Please enter both a title and url',
        name: 'Only letters or dashes for the name field',
        email: 'Please enter a valid email',
        same: 'Please make emails equal',
        taken: 'Sorry that email is taken',
        pass: 'Please enter a valid password, 6-40 characters',
        validate: 'Please contact <a class="d" href="mailto:support@archemarks.com">support</a> to reset your password',
        url:  'Pleae enter a valid url'
    }; 
    this.div = div; 
}; 

View_message.prototype.display = function(type) 
{
    document.getElementById(this.div).innerHTML=this.messages[type];
};

obj_view = new View_message('test_id')
obj_view.display('empty');
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be creating a copy of `this.messages` for each instance of `View_message`.  To prevent that, you could store the messages in the prototype.

Also, you are doing a lookup of the div every time you display a message.  I'd store a reference to the div in the constructor instead.

```
function View_message (div)
{
    this.div = document.getElementsById(div);
}

View_message.prototype.messages = {
    empty: 'Please complete all fields',
    empty_bm: 'Please enter both a title and url',
    name: 'Only letters or dashes for the name field',
    email: 'Please enter a valid email',
    same: 'Please make emails equal',
    taken: 'Sorry that email is taken',
    pass: 'Please enter a valid password, 6-40 characters',
    validate: 'Please contact <a class="d" href="mailto:support@archemarks.com">support</a> to reset your password',
    url:  'Pleae enter a valid url'
};
View_message.prototype.display = function(type)
{
    this.div.innerHTML = this.messages[type];
};
```

Comment: Is a text node pretty much the same thing as innerHTML as far the DOM goes?

Comment: @stack.user.0 - Setting the `innerHTML` of a div to some text creates a text node object behind the scenes.  Getting a reference to that text node and manipulating it directly is just a more direct way of doing it.  Upon closer inspection, I see that at least one of your messages contains HTML.  In that case, you should use HTML.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks...are you saying that HTML can not use the text node...I was gong to update my code base to use this more "direct method"?

Comment: If your message contains html, setting the `nodeValue` of the text node will cause your html code to be displayed on the page. You don't want that. Keep using `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the way you're doing it, but unless you have a lot more functions associated with those error messages, it seems a little overboard to create a prototype for it and instantiate a new object for it.  You could implement the display method in one function that takes the type and the id as arguments.

```
function displayMessage(type, div) {
    var msgs = {
        empty: 'Please complete all fields',
        empty_bm: 'Please enter both a title and url',
        name: 'Only letters or dashes for the name field',
        email: 'Please enter a valid email',
        same: 'Please make emails equal',
        taken: 'Sorry that email is taken',
        pass: 'Please enter a valid password, 6-40 characters',
        validate: 'Please contact <a class="d" href="mailto:support@archemarks.com">support</a> to reset your password',
        url:  'Pleae enter a valid url'
    }; 
    document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = msgs[type];
}
```

If you call it a lot, you could even put the msgs structure into a closure so it doesn't have to be evaluated each time you call it.